# Unable to install packages in python virtual environment in Ubuntu

Tags: python, python-3.x, ubuntu

In my Ubuntu system I have python 3.8. I created virtual environment using Python3.7.
I used below command for creating virtual environment.

```
sudo virtualenv -p /usr/bin/python3.7 venv
```

Then activated the virtual environment using the command source venv/bin/activate , after that when I try to install boto3==1.24.35 by executing requirements.txt using the command

```
sudo pip install -r requirements.txt
```

I am getting the message Requirement already satisfied: boto3==1.24.35 in /usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages. It is not installing boto3 under the virtual environmet so when I execute the application in virtual environmentI am getting the error  "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'boto3'".

Why pip install is not considering virtual environment python version? Please help me to resolve this problem.

Comment: did you activate the virtual env and then did pip install ?

Comment: yes, I activated the virtual environment and then executed the pip install but it is not taking virtual environment python version during packages installation

Comment: try use `python3 -m pip` after activating your venv

Comment: @sahasrara62 Sorry the problem is , I used sudo while creating virtual environment Without sudo the packages are installing. Why with sudo it is not working

Comment: recreate venv again without sudo

Comment: There are several potential reasons why an error may occur during the installation of a package. If you happen to quit the installation process by accident, it could lead to errors and affect its proper functioning.